# Using Entity framework I want to add data to a text box

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

Using Entity framework I want to add data to a text box. I have done this before using a connection string and myReader. But new to EF.

```
 private void displayCust()
    {
        using (Entities c = new Entities())
        {
           cbUsers.ItemsSource = c.customer.ToList();                
        }
    }
```

To display:

```
   private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      using (Entities c = new Entities())
      {
        string sFirst = c.customer.ToString();
        txtFirst.Text = sFirst;
      }
  }
```

Comment: what do you want to show on text box ?

Comment: First as in firstname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you customer object looks like this:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name {get;set}
}
```

You can get the name of the first row in your database like this:

```
using (Entities c = new Entities())
    {
        string sFirst = c.customer.FirstOrDefault().Name.ToString();

        txtFirst.Text = sFirst;

    }
```

Or the customer name with a certain ID:

```
  using (Entities c = new Entities())
    {
        string sFirst = c.customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2).Name.ToString();

        txtFirst.Text = sFirst;

    }
```

Comment: so if I need the second and third etc?

Comment: You can use c.customer.Skip(2).First(). But you should read more information about `LINQ`. :)